# mysql: unknown variable 'key_buffer=16M'

Tags: mysql, servidor, variáveis, login

Em Linux, através da linha de comandos, quando tento realizar *login* com:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Deveria receber a *prompt*:

```
Enter password:
```

Mas ao invés disso recebo o erro:

```
mysql: unknown variable 'key_buffer=16M'
```

De onde origina este erro e como posso solucionar o mesmo?

<sup>Se relevante o servidor corre Ubuntu precise (12.04.1 LTS) com MySQL 5.5.37.</sup>

Comment: Você inseriu essa diretiva `key_buffer` em algum lugar da configuração do MySQL? Ao que me parece o `=` deveria estar com espaços em volta.

Comment: Veja se esse "key_buffer=16M" está em `/etc/my.cnf`

Comment: @AndréRibeiro Está em `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` escrito da seguinte forma: `key_buffer              = 16M
`

Comment: Comente a linha que resolverá seu problema

Comment: @AndréRibeiro Resolverá e desligará o buffer. Eu tenho essa linha na minha configuração (inclusive aumentei o valor por questões de performance), e nunca deu esse erro.

Comment: @bfavaretto Na verdade vai resetar para o valor padrão (8mb) que é bem baixo.

Comment: @Zuul tente trocar por key_buffer_size e veja se funciona.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro Sim, a solução acabou por ser essa. Estou a responder com o que consegui apurar no decorrer do processo, mas se puderes responder com essa indicação, agradecia!

Answer (score 3):

Em complemento da dica/solução apresentada pelo [@AndréRibeiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46799/mysql-unknown-variable-key-buffer-16m?noredirect=1#comment94038_46799), depois de alguns testes, pude observar que:

## Apurar localizações do my.cnf

Não existe um método para apurar onde se encontra o ficheiro `my.cnf`, mas as localizações comuns são:

```
/etc/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf          (no meu caso estava aqui)
$MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf
[datadir]/my.cnf
~/.my.cnf
```

<sup>Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2485758/352449</sup>

## Apurar nome correto da variável

Efetivamente, não sabendo se a variável estava correta ou não, e dado o próprio erro sugerir que a variável é desconhecida, através do [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) executei o seguinte comando:

```sql
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%key_buffer%';
```

Tendo obtido o nome de variável `key_buffer_size` com o valor `8388608`.

<sup>Source: https://serverfault.com/a/550748/128973</sup>

## Documentação

Aprofundando a questão, a documentação faz referência a [`key_buffer_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_key_buffer_size), um pouco estranho pois o `my.cnf` neste e outros servidores está com `key_buffer`. Assumo que se trata de alguma mudança da MySQL, estando os `my.cnf` desatualizados.

---

O problema ficou ultrapassado com a troca do nome de `key_buffer` para `key_buffer_size`.

Answer (score 0):

Vá em `/etc/my.cnf`, procure por "key_buffer" e comente a linha. Tente de novo e verá que dará certo.

Caso dê, vá na(s) linha(s) acima dos seus "key_buffer" e veja se há algo digitado errado.